Как соединить три видеофайла с эффектом плавного перехода без потери качества (python)?
есть три видеофайла:
1 начальная заставка.mp4
2 Основное видео.mp4
3 конечная заставка.mp4
Все что нужно это склеить видео и аудио с эффектом плавного перехода.
Что я пробовал:

Использовал moviepy библиотек. Получилось склеивать файлы но это было очень медленно и увеличение потоков и прочие методы не помогают. Плюс на файлах с большим разрешением появляются проблемы и портится качество.

Пробовал использовать Ffmpeg-python - скорость обработки там заметно выше. Но качество видео все равно портится, плюс сама библиотека довольно сложна.


Может есть еще какие-то способы для решения задачи или готовое приложение? Или возможно есть видеоредактор, которым можно управлять через Python?

Добрый день. Настройте ffmpeg-python на то что бы качество не портилось. Если хотите что-либо делать с видео, лучше либы не найдёте. Для ffmpeg есть так же транзишны - такие как вам нужны. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade
Библиотека не сложна. Покажите код и что именно у вас не получилось.

Спасибо нашел все-таки лучше решение. Установил программу Blender, там есть видеоредактор и можно писать скрипты на python.
С  ffmpeg я разобрался более менее там получается все, кроме того что исходное качество все равно страдает. Но я так понял что это нормально так как видео перекодируется при наложении эффектов. Если костыльное решение резать каждое видео на 2 части и применять эффекты только к тем частям где есть переход, а потом делать склейку, тогда еще более менее норм. Но эти части хоть они и короткие все равно страдают
